# Can we write/read data from/in to localsorage by using javascript from HTTPS web page?

Tags: macos, https, safari, local-storage

I need to write and read data form localstorage when we open HTTPS web pahe. It is possible or Safari afari sequrity dosent allow it? allow it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Local Storage works regardless of the protocol used to load the page.

Note that HTTPS and non-HTTPS pages cannot interact with eachother due to the same-origin policy.

Comment: I believe that HTTPS and non-HTTPS pages can still communicate via cross-document messaging (i.e., `postMessage`), though of course trusting HTTP messages in an HTTPS page is a security concern.  See also browser support http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging .